# MS Project Resource 24hrs/day assigned to 2 Tasks 8Hr Days (8-5) Same Days No Conflict

Tags: calendar, resources, ms-project

I have a Resource (Van) that can be used 24hrs/day 7days/week.

I have 2 tasks that both occur on Monday.
The Project Calendar is Standard.
The Task Calendars are Standard.

The resource is assigned to both tasks.  Both tasks happen between 8a.m. and 5p.m. on the same day.

The tasks can only be performed during that time period on Monday.

No resource conflict. How can the van be at two places at once?

How do I make it show the correct resource conflict?

Comment: So, Answering my own question here.

Change Leveling options to Hour by Hour instead of Day by Day.

Answer (score 0):

So, Answering my own question here.

Change Leveling options to Hour by Hour instead of Day by Day.